# Is there an less verbose way for accepting a group of interfaces in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, model

### Problem

This is a greatly simplified variant of my issue:

I have a model that looks like this:

```ts
interface Instrument {
    name: string;
    // ...more properties that all instruments have in common...
}

interface Guitar extends Instrument {
    type: "classical" | "electric";
    // ...more properties that only a guitar has...
}

interface Flute extends Instrument {
    range: "concert" | "piccolo" | "g-alto" | "g-bass";
    // ...properties that only a flute has...
}

interface Artist {
    instrument: Guitar | Flute;
}
```

Now, every time I add a new instrument, I have to remember to add it to the artist's accepted instruments as well. I am wondering if there is a way for me to define some sort of abstract instrument interface and tell `Artist.instrument` to accept every interface that extends `Instrument`.

### Expectations

So ideally this would look something like this:

```ts
interface Artist {
    instrument: // everything that inherits from or extends Instrument
}
```

I'm open to other approaches too. Let me know if there is even a simpler way for solving this.

### What I've tried

I already tried to simply accept `Instrument` as type for `Artist.instrument`, but that didn't work.

```ts
interface Artist {
    instrument: Instrument
}

interface Guitar extends Instrument {
  type: "classical" | "electric";
}

const guitar: Guitar = {
    name: "Guitar",
    type: "electric"
}

const jimiHendrix: Artist = {
    instrument: {
        name: "Guitar",
        type: "electric"
    }
}
```

In this case, I got the following error:

```
TS2322: Type '{ name: string; type: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Instrument'.   Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'type' does not exist in type 'Instrument'.
```

Comment: "In this case I got errors for every property that was not shared by all instruments." <-- How would that change with `Guitar | Flute`?  Maybe you should show the code that makes the errors in question so that we can understand the use case

Comment: Also, at present your artist only supports a single instrument, but multi-instrumentalists are really common. Are you always necessarily going to have only one instrument per artist? Also, the "right" answer here will likely depend on how you're planning to use `Artist`.

Comment: Re examples: Please be sure to include representative properties in interfaces (just one or two is fine), for instance [like this](https://tsplay.dev/m0bYnw). Because TypeScript's type system is *structural* (based on the shapes of things), not *nominal* (based on the names or identities of types), the `Instrument`, `Flute`, and `Guitar` shown above are all interchangeable (as none of them has any properties) and even interchangeable with `{}`.

Comment: The answer to the main question is *no*; TS doesn't track all possible types that extend interfaces; the type system is structural so that wouldn't even be a finite list (although I suppose one could hope for all *named* types that *explicitly* extend interfaces). Personally I think keeping a manually-maintained union is less awful than any alternative where you try to get the compiler to figure it out.  You could do [this](https://tsplay.dev/NDDeRN), for example, where the types are computed, but then individual instruments have names like `Instrument<"Guitar">` instead of just `Guitar`.

Comment: ^ Does that fully address your question?  If so I could write up an answer explaining (although it would still be nice to see a [mre] in the question).  If not, what am I missing?  (Please mention @jcalz if you reply so that I'm notified)

Comment: One thing that might help you avoid forgetting is to make `Instrument` based on `Guitar`, `Flute`, etc., rather than the other way around, [like this](https://tsplay.dev/wE474W) (I used `type` there instead of `interface` -- see [here for the distinction](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#differences-between-type-aliases-and-interfaces) -- but you could use `interface` for everything in that except `Instrument`, [like this](https://tsplay.dev/mZQ11N).)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Re multi-instrumentalists: I'm aware about that. As I mentioned, this is a greatly simplified example, and my real interface is not even about instruments or artists.
I've updated my exampled as you suggested. Thanks!

Comment: @Marco - Would you add an example of how you're *using* `Artist` that had the errors you mentioned? Or more to the point, how you *want* to use `Artist`? (That was the more important part of [that comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74746027/is-there-an-less-verbose-way-for-accepting-a-group-of-interfaces-in-typescript?noredirect=1#comment131919573_74746027).)

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for your idea. That's actually an interesting way of solving the problem. I'll consider doing so.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Done. In the meantime, I also found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74768938/7972786) that works for me. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally was able to solve the issue with a workaround.

As shown in my question, defining the instrument inside the artist object doesn't work. It works if I define it outside and then pass the variable to the artist object.

```ts
interface Instrument {
  name: string;
}

interface Guitar extends Instrument {
  type: "classical" | "electric";
}

interface Artist {
  instrument: Instrument;
}

const guitar: Guitar = {
  name: "Guitar",
  type: "electric",
};

const jimiHendrix: Artist = {
  instrument: guitar,
};
```

This solves the issue for me, but I still don't see a reason why defining valid instrument properties inside `Artist.instrument` gets rejected by TS.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Of course your playground link works. It defines `Artist.instrument` in the verbose way, that I was trying to prevent (`instrument: Guitar | Flute`). Try replacing that line with `instrument: Instrument` and you'll also get the error.

Comment: Ah, okay, missed that bit. Here's the inline way to tell TypeScript it's a `Guitar`: https://tsplay.dev/WG48Vw But there may well be better definitions of `Artist` (and/or `Instrument`) depending on how you want to *use* `Artist`, which is why I keep asking that question.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the attempt you made which produced errors looked something like this:

```js
interface Instrument {
    key: string;
}

interface Guitar extends Instrument {
    isElectric?: boolean;
    stringCount: number;
}

interface Flute extends Instrument {
    bodyType: "wood" | "metal";
}

interface Artist {
    instrument: Instrument
}

const artist:Artist = {
    instrument: {
        key: "A",
        stringCount: 12,
    },
};
```

Where the `stringCount` property produces this error:

```
Type '{ key: string; stringCount: number; }' is not assignable to type 'Instrument'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'stringCount' does not exist in type 'Instrument'.
```

The issue here is that you could have literally any possible property defined by an interface which inherits from `Instrument` and TypeScript has no way of validating what it doesn't know.

One solution is to break out the instrument definition into a separate variable which TypeScript can verify:

```js
const instrument:Guitar = {
    key: "A",
    stringCount: 12,
};
const artist:Artist = {
    instrument,
};
```

This produces no errors. TypeScript is happy because the `instrument` variable can be verified, and it can be assigned to the `instrument` property of `artist` because it satisfies the interface.

Another solution is to make `Artist` a generic type where you can more explicitly define what kind of instrument the artist plays (defaulting to `Instrument` for convenience):

```js
interface Artist<T extends Instrument=Instrument> {
    instrument: T
}

const artist:Artist<Guitar> = {
    instrument: {
        key: "A",
        stringCount: 12,
    }
};
```